# I want to do some aggregations with the help of Group By function in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science

My dataset consists of a date column in 'datetime64[ns]' dtype; it also has a price and a no. of sales column.
I want to calculate the monthly VWAP (Volume Weighted Average Price ) of the stock. 
( VWAP = sum(price*no.of sales)/sum(no. of sales) )

What I applied is:-
created a new dataframe column of month and year using pandas functions.

Now, I want monthly VWAP from this dataset which I modified, also, it should be distinct by year.
For eg. - March,2016 and March,2017 should have their seperate VWAP monthly values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from defining a function to count *vwap* for the current
month (group of rows):

```
def vwap(grp):
    return (grp.price * grp.salesNo).sum() / grp.salesNo.sum()
```

Then apply it to monthly groups:

```
df.groupby(df.dat.dt.to_period('M')).apply(vwap)
```

Using the following test DataFrame:

```
         dat  price  salesNo
0 2018-05-14  120.5       10
1 2018-05-16   80.0       22
2 2018-05-20   30.2       12
3 2018-08-10   75.1       41
4 2018-08-20   92.3       18
5 2019-05-10   10.0       33
6 2019-05-20   20.0       41
```

(containing data from the same months in different years), I got:

```
dat
2018-05    75.622727
2018-08    80.347458
2019-05    15.540541
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, the result contains **separate** entries for May in both
years from the source data.